# Audio not playing in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to program a script that when you hit an enemy it plays a sound, problem is I can't get it to play the sound it sees the audio source but my script won't pass the clip to it.

Here is the code I currently have:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Audio;

public class makeanoise : MonoBehaviour
{
    public AudioClip hurtSound;
    public AudioSource soundSource;

    private void Update()
    {

        if (!soundSource.isPlaying)
        {
            soundSource.clip = hurtSound;
            soundSource.Play();
        }
    }
}
```

how do you get the audio source to play the sound? because not even my team mates know to do it

Comment: Are you sure your sound isn't playing over and over every frame therefore no actual sound can be heard? Isn't `Update` per frame?

Comment: it isn't even passing a clip to the source but i will put it in an if statement

Comment: I think you have a design error here, not that unity savy but I'd say the play a sound if hit function should be part of the enemy object. Just a suggestion, maybe others have better ideas.

Comment: @Vulpex it should work like this.

Comment: @Charleh yes i am sure that it is not playing it really fast i just tried it again and it is still not working with the edited code

Comment: Too many reasons why Audio may not play. I've covered most of them in a very likely order for you and future people that run into them. Make sure to go over them in order

Answer (score 23):

> I am trying to program a script that when you hit an enemy it plays a
>   sound

Use collision detection + collider instead of the Update function to detect the hit then play audio:

```
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
{
    soundSource.Play();
}
```

If 2D game, use `OnCollisionEnter2D` instead.

> I can't get it to play the sound it sees the audio source but my
>   script won't pass the clip to it.

There are just many reasons why Audio many not play in Unity. Your sound won't play **not** because you put it in the `Update` function.The reason it's not the `Update` function like some mentioned is because you protected it with `if (!soundSource.isPlaying)` so it will only play again only when the first one is doe playing.

**Reasons why audio won't play in Unity**: (From likely to unlikely)

**1**.The `AudioClip` is not assigned.

This is your AudioClip

```
public AudioClip hurtSound;
```

If `hurtSound` not assigned or initialized in the Editor or via code, Unity won't throw any error. It simply won't play.

Simply drag the audio to your `hurtSound` slot and you should hear the sound. Sometimes, the audio reference is lost so simply repeat this step again to recreate the reference.

[image]

---

**2**.Editor is muted. If the Editor is muted no sound will be coming out of it but the build should have a sound. Check and disable the mute on the Editor.

[image]

---

**3**.Playing the sound every frame. This mistake is not uncommon and it causes the AudioSource not have time to play the audio over and over again.

*Example of this mistake*:

```
private void Update()
{
    soundSource.Play();
}
```

*Possible fix*:

Check the Audio is playing first before playing it.(Did this in the code from this question which is correct!)

```
private void Update()
{

    if (!soundSource.isPlaying)
    {
        soundSource.Play();
    }
}
```

---

**4**.The GameObject the `AudioSource` is attached to has been destroyed.
This is also common. If the GameObject the `AudioSource` has been attached to is destroyed, the Audio would not play.

The fix is to attach the  `AudioSource` to GameObject that doesn't destroy. An empty GameObject is fine.

Or you can play the Audio, wait for it to finish playing then destroy it:

```
IEnumerator playAudio()
{
    //Play Audio
    soundSource.Play();

    //Wait until it's done playing
    while (soundSource.isPlaying)
        yield return null;

    //Now, destroy it
    Destroy(gameObject);
}
```

---

**5**.The GameObject the `AudioSource` is attached to has been deactivated.

If the GameObject that has the `Audiosource` is deactivated, the audio would also stop. Don't deactivate the `AudioSource` GameObject. See **#4** for possible workarounds.

[image]

---

**6**.The code is not even executing.

You must make sure that the `Play` code is even executing. A simple `Debug.Log` function call is enough to determine this.

```
private void Update()
{

    if (!soundSource.isPlaying)
    {
        soundSource.clip = hurtSound;
        soundSource.Play();
        Debug.Log("Played");
    }
}
```

[image]

If you can't see that log in the Console tab then the code is not executing.

*A.Script is not attached to a GameObject. Attach it to a GameObject:*

[image]

*B.The GameObject the script is attached to is not Active. Activate it from the Editor:*

[image]

*C.The script is not enabled. Enable it:*

[image]

---

**7**.The `AudioSource` is muted or volume is `0`.

[image]

---

**8**.The `AudioListener` component is not present. This is very unlikely since it is automatically attached to your camera. Check if it is deleted by mistake then re-attach it to the camera. It must be attached to the camera not to any other object.

[image]

---

**9**.Bad Audio. Replace with another Audio.

**10**.Bug. Go to the *Help* ---> *Report a Bug..* menu and file for a bug report.

This is what to do if everything above has failed. This is unlikely the problem but could happen when there is a big OS update.

Comment: There is a small typo in your code. That should be `while (soundSource.isPlaying)` not `while (!soundSource.isPlaying)`

Comment: no i only want it to play at the moment if it is not playing it it won't execute the code if it is if(soundsource.isplaying) since the sound source isn't playing when it gets to the code it has to be !soundsoure.isplaying since the sound source is not playing

Comment: @TheAmericanFox Is the reply to me? Did you check what's in my answer?

Comment: Ahh! I had number 2. I was stucked for a half year :D
Thank you for your help, sir!

Comment: This really helped me to figure out the problem.,,, me was 2, but I had to change to GAME VIEW instead of SCENE VIEW... which I probably would not have seen if it weren't for the great comments.. ;] oh, and before the main routine ---> `using UnityEngine.Audio`

Comment: I have one more to add, sadly.  Reboot your computer.  Restarting Unity was not enough.  Even builds had no audio, until I rebooted.

Comment: Wow, I've got an AudioSource, I can see it in the debugger and step through the code that sets volume to 0.75f and calls play ... it has a valid clip, too, but it still says volume = 1f and isPlaying = false ... Unity 2021.3.12f1 ... something fishy is going in here 

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a AudioListener in the scene and also check the 3D sounds settings, the most usual thing is having the AudioListener attached to the main camera.

Check if in the scene is there any [AudioListener](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-AudioListener.html) and the Settings of your [AudioSource](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AudioSource-clip.html)

Comment: there is the camera has an audio listener by default

Comment: Is your gameobject close to the camera? Remove the Script that plays the audio and leave a long audio (like a song) and set in the audiosource "Play on Awake/Enable" and try to move the camera the closer you can to the gameobject. You should listen it.

Comment: the audio source is playing in 2d space it doesn't matter how far away from the source you will still hear it

Comment: Check in the Audio Source -> Spatial Blend (2D-3D)

Comment: Once you hear the sound you will have to code all the behaviour of getting hitted and playing the audio.

Comment: i already have the logic for when the enemy gets hit. i cant get the sound to play

Comment: I had issues with the sound in a 2D game, we fixed it checking the audiosource settings but I don't remember how we configured all the component.

Comment: this is the error that pops up in the console:                                                  NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
makeanoise.Start () (at Assets/Scripts/makeanoise.cs:24)

Answer (score 0):

One more thing that can cause that it the Pitch settings - i had mine on 0 - i could see the audio playing in the mixer - but no sound would be heard - moved pitch back to 1 - and everything worked well.

Answer (score 0):

Just to help anyone else out, the pitch settings like ash a mentioned actually can cause some strange bugs, the pitch of my audio source was set to -1 as I have a mechanic where points increase the sfx pitch by clicking on things in succession. using `AudioSource.PlayClip` at point allowed the sound to play but I then removed `AudioSource.PlayClipAtPoint` to use the cached `AudioSource`, made sure the pitch initialized at 1f when I wanted the GameOver sounds to play and all worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by playing `AudioSource.clip` at the position of the main camera. Passing in a `Vector3` with `x`, `y`, and `z` all equal to `0` played the sound, but it was quieter. I never got `AudioSource.Play()` to work.

```
AudioSource.PlayClipAtPoint(audioSource.clip, mainCamera.transform.position);
```

Answer (score 0):

The checklist provided by @Programmer helped me to remove other possibilities and find yet another potential problem to consider...

If your audio works fine in the Unity editor but not in the build, it could be that you are using `OnValidate()` to store the reference to your `AudioSource` component in a `private` field. Specifically, [Unity does not serialize values in private fields unless explicitly instructed](https://forum.unity.com/threads/how-does-onvalidate-work.616372/)

How to confirm / fix it:

1. Enable "Development Build" so the build will report issues
2. The build log shows `NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object` when you try to play or otherwise access the `AudioSource`.
3. Add `[SerializeField]` to any private vars set using `OnValidate()` to be sure the reference is serialized:

```cs
[SerializeField] private AudioSource audioSource;
void OnValidate()
{
    audioSource = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
}
```

[image: build settings]

Answer (score 0):

Landed on this old question as I had the same issue, but solutions here didn't fix - I suspect my problem was likely too obvious to have been included on answers given so far, but sometimes there's no such thing as too obvious...

There is a global project audio level, which was set to 0 (I presume I inadvertently changed it myself, as it seems an odd default). On v. 2021.3, can change via Edit > Project Settings > Audio, and there's a Global Volume setting at the top.